# Adding new In-app purchases through Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am using Application Loader to add 3 new In-App Purchases. I have 14 currently for sale.

When I add the new 3 (with hosted content), validate, then press Deliver.

I get this error

> The archive for In-App Purchase 'com.xxx.xxx' is invalid.
>
> The 'ContentVersion' in the ContentInfo.plist must have a higher value
>   than the current version.

Where com.xxx.xxx is an old, live hosted content In-app Purchase...

If I change the ContentVersion of com.xxx.xxx will it affect users who have bought it? Why would I need to change it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an Apple error and it's fixed itself. Didn't have to change anything. Just waited for them to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The number of In-App Purchases won't play a factor: Apple Quote: "Application Loader supports a maximum of 1,000 In-App Purchases per application." from [Using Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf).

Make sure all the Product IDs you've set in the **In-App Purchase summary** are identical to the ones associated with the ones located in your app's `.plist` file. According to Apple's: **In-App Purchase Programming Guide**, changes to the plist identifiers may cause issues with the users' previous purchases in the app: [image]
Checkout Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on [In-App Purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). It's pretty straightforward and regularly updated.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the ContentVersion string in your ContentInfo.plist from ver 1.0 to 2.0 before submitting to iTunes connect. If your IAP was not approved by apple then it would just overwrite version 1.0 but if your updating an approved IAP you have to incremnet the version.